# I forgot the name of the test to compare multiple timepoints in a series to time point zero

Tags: time-series, anova

This is killing me... classic tip-of-the-tongue moment.

I have data in a series, and I want to determine the significance of each point in the series to the first (aka timepoint or dose drug curve point zero). The test functions like a modified anova, and it begins with a d... I think. My googling skills are not up to snuff apparently because I can't seem to remember the name. Any ideas what this test is called?

The correct answer is a Dunnett test. The wiki page is great for this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunnett%27s_test In short, the test is designed to correct for multiple comparisons when determining significance of all points in a series to the initial point. Think of a time-course, or drug dose response, and you want to see if any point in the series is significant with respect with time point zero or dose zero.

Comment: Duncan? Dunnett?

Comment: @user2974951, YES, THATS IT! Dunnett. Please suggest this as an answer so I can up vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already commented in your question, you were looking for the Dunnett's test for multiple comparisons, which compares each treatment with a control (reference), such as when we want to compare many drugs to a single established drug with known effect.